# Azure Webjob Powershell Error Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-powershell

Azure WebJobs run Powershell scripts, but Invoke-Sqlcmd fails in WebJob. How to fix?
Script works in PowerShell ISE locally but fails in Azure Webjob:

```
    $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'SELECT AlertLine FROM HR.AlertRecordsOpenInline;' `
    -ServerInstance 'xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net' `
    -Username 'xxxxx@xxxxxx' -Password 'xxxxxx' -Database 'xxxxxx'
foreach($item in $result){
    [string]$Results += ($item.AlertLine)
    }
$Results
```

WebJob Run Details Output:

```
[09/02/2016 16:09:00 > da15b0: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[09/02/2016 16:09:00 > da15b0: SYS INFO] Run script 'Invoke-Sqlcmd.ps1' with script host - 'PowerShellScriptHost'
[09/02/2016 16:09:00 > da15b0: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ] Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a 
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ] cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ] name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\Invoke-Sqlcmd\ni4ywn1l.sgn\Invoke-Sqlcmd.ps1:1 
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ] char:11
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ] + $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'SELECT AlertLine FROM 
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ] HR.AlertRecordsOpenInline; ...
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ] +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Sqlcmd:String) [], Comma 
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ]    ndNotFoundException
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: ERR ]  
[09/02/2016 16:09:01 > da15b0: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

Have searched and searched but am stuck, not sure what to try next. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLPS module is not installed in the Azure WebJobs environment and I'm not aware of a way to install additional modules. Have you tried [Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/), if it doesn't have the modules you need you can add your own or install modules from the gallery.

Comment: Runbooks in Azure Automation are the solution - thank you.